# log exceptions using Exception filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to add exceptions to a file using exception filters.
this is my `ILog` interface.

```
public interface ILog
{
    void Log(Importance importance, Func<string> message);

    void Log(Importance importance, Func<string> message, Exception   exception);
}
```

How can I log exceptions in OnExceptipn method below?

```
public class LoggingExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILog _log;

    public LoggingExceptionFilter(ILogFactory logFactory)
    {
        _log = logFactory.Create("LoggingExceptionFilter");
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // what to do here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just grab the exception like this:
`Exception ex = context.Exception;`

And then log the exception using your library.

Whatever else you want to do after that is up to you - whether you want to continue execution, or return an error to the client. For example I have got this snippet in my Web API projects to return an appropriate HTTP error code:

```
HttpStatusCode statuscode;

if (context.Exception is HttpResponseException)
{
    var HTTPex = (HttpResponseException)context.Exception;
    statuscode = HTTPex.Response.StatusCode;
}
else
{
    statuscode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
} 

context.response = response;
```